# What does this icon indicate?

Tags: notifications, notification-icons, app-icons

[image: Please tell]
What does this icon indicate it is coming in my statusbar recently and its worrying me..

Comment: On the left, no related information is shown, I'm using Redmi note prime running android 4.4.4

Comment: No app has this icon either, i've been getting verification SMS's frequently when i swipe the SMS this icon shows up.. I think it is some sort of virus or something

Comment: [edit] your question to give as much information as possible to help others help you. Right now your question looks like it is icon related but the root cause may be something else. If you don't bother to ask with all details, you are not likely to get answers